# I am designing a chrome extension that will search for text on a page and hyperlink it. I am having trouble hyperlinking the text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, hyperlink, content-script

Here is my existing contentScript.js:

```
const words = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, li, td, caption, span, a');

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'tag';
let text = document.createTextNode('TAG');

for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    if(words[i].innerHTML.includes('COVID-19')|| words[i].innerHTML.includes('covid-19')){
       words[i].innerHTML = words[i].innerHTML.replace('COVID-19', 'THIS WORKS');
       div.appendChild(text);
}
```

This code successfully replaces "TEST" with "THIS WORKS" on most web pages. I would like to replace "TEST" with "[THIS WORKS](https://www.youtube.com)" and direct the user to a given link. Do you have any insights? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replace function supports HTML so you can do the following

Replace:

```
words[i].innerHTML = words[i].innerHTML.replace('COVID-19', 'THIS WORKS');
```

With (Replace the CDC link with whichever link you would like to use):

```
words[i].innerHTML = words[i].innerHTML.replace('COVID-19', '<a href="https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/index.html" target="_blank">THIS WORKS</a>');
```

Best of luck with your extension!

Comment: you're a legend

Comment: Happy to help! if it resolved your problem don't forget to mark it as correct, have a good week